# Category matching query does not exist Error

Tags: python, django

I want to post an url and save to Link model. But I got this error:

```
Category matching query does not exist
```

my views.py

```
def category_detail(request, category_name):
    if request.POST:
        form = CreateLinkForm(request.POST)
        user = request.user
        if form.is_valid():
            link = form.save(commit=False)
            link.user = user 
            link.category = Category.objects.get(name=category_name)
            link.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('category_detail', args=[category_name]))
    else:
        form = CreateLinkForm()
    links = Link.objects.filter(category__name=category_name)
    return render_to_response("category_detail.html", {"links":links, "form":form, "category_name":category_name}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

When I query at terminal python manage.py shell I get this :

```
>>> from link.models import Category
>>> Category.objects.all()
[<Category: <django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x22dbfd0> Programlama>, <Category: <django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x22de110> Foto>, <Category: <django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x22dbfd0> Sanat>]
>>> Category.objects.get(name="Foto")
<Category: <django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x22dbed0> Foto>
```

Link model:

```
class Link(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    posted_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    url = models.URLField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s %s" %(self.url, self.title, self.category)
```

CreateLinkForm:

```
class CreateLinkForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Link 
        exclude = ["user", "posted_at", "category"]
```

So what is my wrong ? Why I got this error `Category matching query does not exist`

Comment: Please post your `Link` model and `CreateLinkForm`

Comment: Is `category_name` definitely what you expect?  Try `pdb`/`ipdb` and inspect what the value is and thus what is being queried

Comment: Please paste the traceback

Comment: I posted Link and form. Still I couldt figure out.

Comment: When you're passing the category name to the view function, do you actually have a corresponding Category object for that variable? I.e. `category_name= "foo"` and there is a Category object in the DB where name='foo'? Django will throw an exception when using the Model function get() if there are no records found.

Answer (score 0):

If `category_name` is an argument in your view, and you would like to set it equal to `link.category`, then in your `views.py` do this:

```
if form.is_valid():
  ...
  link.category = category_name
  ...
  # your other view code
```

The reason the `view` is erroring out is that you are trying to set field equal to a get() query, but Django is expecting to get an integer argument here because the `category` field in your `Link` model is a `Foreign Key` to the your `Category` model.

Comment: I solved the problem. I did form action like this: <form action=""> and its ok.